# How can I pass an array of structures to another function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to pass an array of structs as pointer in another function. But the compiler just refuses.

I build up this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Values{
    char timestamp[21];
    char temperature[2];
    int tmp;
};

char *readString(char out[], FILE *fp){// Reading and storing the input values, out = the string that this func returns
    int ch, i;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)))
        if(ch == '"') break;

    for(i=0;EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp));++i){
        if(ch == '"') break;
        out[i] = ch;
    }

    out[i]='\0';
    return out;
}

void printValues(struct Values * v, int i){ //just a printing method, for printing the values, i = the amount of values I have
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<i; j++){
        printf("%s \t : \t %s \t :\t %d \n\n", v[j]->timestamp, v[j]->temperature, v[j]->tmp);
    }
}

void makeTmpIntegers(struct Values values[], int i){ //making temperatures integers so I can use them in sorts, i = the amount of values I have
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<i;j++){
        values[j].tmp = atoi(values[j].temperature);
    }
}

int main(void){ //The beginning of the programm, what did you expect?
    struct Values values[8223];
    FILE *file = fopen("hum.txt", "r" );
    int i=0; //the number of every stored value (for the timestamps)
    int k=0; //the number of every stored value (for the temperatures)

    if (file != NULL ){
        char tempString [21];
        int flag = 1;
        while(*readString(tempString, file)){ //if the readStrinf outputs "/0" == "" (end of FILE)
            if(flag == 1){strcpy(values[i].timestamp, tempString); flag++; i++;}
            else if(flag == 2){strcpy(values[k].temperature, tempString); flag--; k++;}
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    makeTmpIntegers(values, i);

    printValues(&values, i);

    return 0;
}
```

I know for a fact that I can pass the struct from a function to another (it works fine that way), but I want to pass pointers (memory reasons).

I have been trying to do it at the function called printValues()

In this case the compiler does not compile. This is the message I get:

```
In function 'printValues':
24  46  [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct Values')
24  63  [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct Values')
24  82  [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct Values')
In function 'main':
53  17  [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'printValues' from incompatible pointer type
21  6   [Note] expected 'struct Values *' but argument is of type 'struct Values (*)[8223]'
```

Plus if I initialize the function like this: `void printValues(struct Values * v[], int i)`
It does compile but it does not prints the values at all

*I know that the correct way to read an integer from a txt file, is not like this but I couldn't figure something else out*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is OK:

```
struct Values{
    char timestamp[21];
    char temperature[2];
    int tmp; };
```

So are these two function signatures:

```
void printValues(struct Values * v, int i) { ... }

void makeTmpIntegers(struct Values values[], int i) { ... }
```

This is WRONG:

```
v[j]->timestamp, v[j]->temperature, ...
```

Substitute:

```
v[j].timestamp, v[j].temperature, ...
```

ALSO:

Change `printValues(&values, i);` to `printValues(values, i);`

I haven't checked carefully for any other errors, but this should get you moving in the right direction...

---

ADDENDUM:

In both of the examples above, `printValues(struct Values * v, int i)` and `makeTmpIntegers(struct Values values[], int i)`, you're *ALREADY* "passing by pointer".  You just need to fix your syntax, as in my examples.

As Oppen said below:

> Also, note that passing an array argument in C is functionally
>   equivalent to passing a pointer, no copy is involved, so I'm not sure
>   what memory reasons stop you from just passing the array of structs
>   directly...

Comment: Yea, I knew that. I know that I can pass a struct to another function that way. I want to pass the pointer fo that specific struct to the function printValues. This is my question, why it doesn't work with pointers

Comment: Also, note that passing an array argument in C is functionally equivalent to passing a pointer, no copy is involved, so I'm not sure what memory reasons stop you from just passing the array of structs directly.

Comment: ow, ok I did not know that. Thank you for the information